# How do I removeClass of a class whilst hovering

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover

I'm simply trying to remove a class (to hide it), when I hover a different class. I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong, I assume there is a simple fix.

```
        <div class="description">
            <h2>Writer - London</h2>
            <p>Helene is a French born, London raised writer exploring topics ranging from <mark class="red">art</mark>, <mark class="blue">history</mark>, <mark class="green">feminism</mark> and <mark class="purple">social issues</mark>.</p>
            <p>Her website is currently being <u>updated</u>. Please click on the links to the left to be directed to her work.</p>
        </div>`

       <ul class="projectList">
        <li class="projectImage1"><a class="btn" href="kwao.html">Philomena 
         Kwao<span><img src="helene images/philomena.jpg" alt=""height="580" 
         width="370" /></span></a>
         </li>`
```

I want this action to take place when I hover over the word 'feminism' that has the class "green".

```
$('mark.green').hover(
function() {
$this.removeClass('.projectImage1')
});`
```

**update** Just to clarify, my intention is to completely hide the class when the other is hovered. In css this would be - display none.

Comment: You're looking for `$(this).removeClass()`, although `$(this)` would refer to the `<mark>` element. I think you're trying to remove the class from the `<li>` element, which would be `$('li.projectImage1').removeClass('.projectImage1')`.

Comment: I tried this before I asked the question, didn't work unfortunately

Comment: You want the `.projectImage` class to be removed from `li.projectImage1` when you hover over `mark.green`?

Comment: I'm trying to remove the class from '<li>' only when I hover over 'mark.green'

Comment: @JordanMiguel do you want it to be added back when you stop hovering?

Comment: @MichaelCoker yep

Answer (score 0):

```
$('mark.green').hover(function() {
    $('. projectList > li').removeClass('.projectImage1')
});`
```

Comment: I think you mean... `('.projectList > li').removeClass('projectImage1')`?

Comment: Yes, by mistake I added a dot to remove class

Comment: And the space in `. projectList`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want it to toggle the class when you hover, create a variable for the element based on the initial class so you can reference it with or without the class, then toggle the class of the variable.

```js
var $projectImage = $('li.projectImage1');
$("mark.green").hover(function() {
  $projectImage.removeClass("projectImage1");
},function() {
  $projectImage.addClass("projectImage1");
});
```

```css
.projectImage1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description">
  <h2>Writer - London</h2>
  <p>Helene is a French born, London raised writer exploring topics ranging from <mark class="red">art</mark>, <mark class="blue">history</mark>, <mark class="green">feminism</mark> and <mark class="purple">social issues</mark>.</p>
  <p>Her website is currently being <u>updated</u>. Please click on the links to the left to be directed to her work.</p>
</div>

<ul class="projectList">
  <li class="projectImage1"><a class="btn" href="kwao.html">Philomena 
         Kwao<span><img src="helene images/philomena.jpg" alt=""height="580" 
         width="370" /></span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **toggleClass()** function, like this.

```js
$('mark.green').hover(function() {
    $('.projectList > li').toggleClass('toggle-className')
});
```

```css
.toggle-className{
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description">
            <h2>Writer - London</h2>
            <p>Helene is a French born, London raised writer exploring topics ranging from <mark class="red">art</mark>, <mark class="blue">history</mark>, <mark class="green">feminism</mark> and <mark class="purple">social issues</mark>.</p>
            <p>Her website is currently being <u>updated</u>. Please click on the links to the left to be directed to her work.</p>
        </div>`

       <ul class="projectList">
        <li class="projectImage1 toggle-className"><a class="btn" href="kwao.html">Philomena 
         Kwao<span><img src="helene images/philomena.jpg" alt=""height="580" 
         width="370" /></span></a>
         </li>`
```